# Facetgrid to plot stacked normalised counts - Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid

I'm aiming to use Seaborn facet grid to plot counts of values but normalised, rather than pure counts. Using below, each row should display each unique value in `Item`. The x-axis should display `Num` and the values come from `Label`.

However, each row isn't being partitioned. The same data is displayed for each `Item`.

```
import pandas as pd
import Seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({      
    'Num' : [1,2,1,2,3,2,1,3,2],
    'Label' : ['A','B','C','B','A','C','C','A','B'],   
    'Item' : ['Up','Left','Up','Left','Down','Right','Up','Down','Right'],      
    })

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, 
              row = 'Item', 
              row_order = ['Up','Right','Down','Left'],                           
              aspect = 2, 
              height = 4, 
              sharex = True,
              legend_out = True
              )

g.map(sns.histplot, x = 'Num', hue = 'Label', data = df, multiple = 'fill', shrink=.8) 
g.add_legend()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try `g.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, x='Num', hue = 'Label', multiple = 'fill', shrink=.8)`. I'm not good at seaborn, I just look it up at https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html and `map_dataframe` seems work better than `map`.

Comment: This seems better but `hue` doesn't work?

Comment: It's because all 'Left' items are from Label B and all 'Down' items are from Label A. That's why you can't see the `hue`.

Comment: They are still different for each Item though. That's probably a diff question though. Thanks