# "stack" does not work for seaborn facet plot

Tags: python, seaborn

I tried to use the "multiple = stack" option in the **histplot** function with a **FacetGrid**, but I can't get the proper plot with no error. Any help/thought is appreciated.

Here is a reproducible example w/ **Python 3.8 + seaborn==0.11.2 + pandas==1.3.4**

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# test data
data = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
facet = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
group = [1, 2] * 4
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {"data": data, "facet": facet, "group": group})

# single histplot can stacked
sns.histplot(data = df, x = "data", hue = "group", multiple = "stack")

# facet plot can not
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col=None,  row="facet", hue = "group")
g.map(sns.histplot, "data", **{"stat": "count", "multiple": "stack", "binwidth": 0.1})
# also tried this
# g.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, "data", multiple = "stack", binwidth = .1) 
g.add_legend()
```

Here is the output for single histplot that works:

[image: single stack works]

But I cannot to do it together with facetgrid: **Noted that if stacked correctly it should be 3 instead of 2 for both facet.**

[image: multiple cannot work]

Comment: See also [Facetgrid to plot stacked normalised counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67014156/facetgrid-to-plot-stacked-normalised-counts-seaborn)

Comment: @JohanC Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! The trick is putting the "hue" inside the map_dataframe (can not be the map here) statement instead of the FacetGrid statement.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="facet")
g.map_dataframe(sns.histplot, x = "data", hue = "group",  multiple = "stack", binwidth = .1)
```